# Accessing pages on Google Sites to load on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

Via javascript (jQuery) I'm trying to load the contents of some pages from Google Sites onto elements in pages in a different site. Using jQuery's load I get the expectable:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sites.google.com/site/foo/home. No 'Access-Control-
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://bar' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried with CORS, using the code below (which I found at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), but got the same result.

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

function makeCorsRequest() {
  var url = 'https://sites.google.com/site/edumonkihelp/test0';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  xhr.onload = function() {return xhr.responseText;};
  xhr.onerror = function() {alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');};
  xhr.send();
}
```

So I guess I have two questions:
1. Can you access the contents of pages in Google Sites?
2. Are there any other similar services out there that would allow you to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Sites Data API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ContentFeed) you can use the `path` parameter to fetch that particular page located at `http://sites.google.com/site/siteName/path/to/the/page`:

```
GET /feeds/content/domainName/siteName?path=/path/to/the/page
```

In order to perform Ccoss-domain requests using [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) specify `dataType: 'jsonp'`

### Example

The example demonstrates how to retrieve page located at `https://sites.google.com/site/nokiaofficescontacts/hq`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/nokiaofficescontacts?path=/hq&alt=json',
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log('Page was succesfully retrieved');
        console.log(data.feed.entry[0].title); //print Page Title
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

> Note: `alt=json` is specified to request a response in JSON format.

Comment: This works. A problem that I should but did not foresee was that Google uses a number of css classes to format the page. Those are naturally not included in the contents of the page.  Also the side bar, the header and the footer won't be included, they are not part of that page but of the site. All very logical!